# AngularJS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'getVehicles' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I got stuck on this error. I can't seem to find the cause of it.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getVehicles' of undefined
>
> at new <anonymous>
>    (https://localhost:44334/App/Controllers/tripsController.js:23:27)

My controller:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("JourneyApp").controller("tripsController",
    ["tripsService", "vehicleService", function(tripsService, vehicleService) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.vehicles = [];

        vehicleService.getVehicles().then(function(results) {
            vm.vehicles = results.data;
        });
    }]);
}());
```

And this is my service:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("JourneyApp").factory("vehicleService",
        ["$http", "authService",
            function($http, authService) {

                var serviceBase = "https://localhost:44334/";
                var vehicleServiceFactory = {};

                var _getVehicles = function() {
                    return $http.get(serviceBase + "api/vehicles/user",
                            { headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer" + authService.authentication.token } })
                        .then(function(results) {
                            return results;
                        });
                }
                vehicleServiceFactory.getVehicles = _getVehicles;
            }
        ]
    );
}());
```

Comment: Did u include `tripsController.js` file in your `<script>`

Comment: Your factory doesn't return anything. So it actually returns undefined. So undefined is the service created by the factory, and is injected in the controller.

Comment: `vehicleServiceFactory.getVehicles = _getVehicles; return vehicleServiceFactory`

Comment: @dfsq Yes, that! Can't believe I missed something that obvious, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("JourneyApp").factory("vehicleService",
        ["$http", "authService",
            function($http, authService) {
                var vehicleServiceFactory = this;

                var serviceBase = "https://localhost:44334/";                    

                var _getVehicles = function() {
                    return $http.get(serviceBase + "api/vehicles/user",
                            { headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer" + authService.authentication.token } })
                        .then(function(results) {
                            return results;
                        });
                }
                vehicleServiceFactory.getVehicles = _getVehicles;
            }
        ]
    );
}());
```

You miss the binding between this and the vehicleServiceFactory